# Paypal PHP SDK for Classic APIs?

Tags: php, paypal

Which SDK is designed to work with classic APIs - e.g. encrypt a 'Buy Now' button on my website, handle the IPN callback?

I have read the SDK descriptions on GitHub, pages on https://developer.paypal.com and searched, but none cover the 'old-school' usage vs the new REST API.